# Time sequence in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sequence

Below is the sample of dataframe (df):-

|  | alpha | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 5 |
| 1 | a | 8 |
| 2 | a | 4 |
| 3 | b | 2 |
| 4 | b | 1 |

I know how to make the sequence (numbers) as per the group:

```
df["serial"] = df.groupby("alpha").cumcount()+1
```

|  | alpha | value | serial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | a | 8 | 2 |
| 2 | a | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | b | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | b | 1 | 2 |

But instead of number I need date-time in sequence having 30 mins interval:

**Expected result:**

|  | alpha | value | serial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 5 | 2021-01-01 23:30:00 |
| 1 | a | 8 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 2 | a | 4 | 2021-01-02 00:30:00 |
| 3 | b | 2 | 2021-01-01 23:30:00 |
| 4 | b | 1 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply multiply your result with a `pd.Timedelta`:

```
print ((df.groupby("alpha").cumcount()+1)*pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)+pd.Timestamp("2021-01-01 23:00:00"))

0   2021-01-01 23:30:00
1   2021-01-02 00:00:00
2   2021-01-02 00:30:00
3   2021-01-01 23:30:00
4   2021-01-02 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `to_datetime` and `groupby` with `cumcount`, and then multiplying by `pd.Timedelta` for 30 minutes:

```
>>> df['serial'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 23:30:00') + df.groupby('alpha').cumcount() * pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)
>>> df
  alpha  value              serial
0     a      5 2021-01-01 23:30:00
1     a      8 2021-01-02 00:00:00
2     a      4 2021-01-02 00:30:00
3     b      2 2021-01-01 23:30:00
4     b      1 2021-01-02 00:00:00
>>>
```